When running npm list command, what does npm ERR! code ELSPROBLEMS mean?
When running the below npm command, I am getting an error.
npm list @my-ui-fwk/core

npm ERR! code ELSPROBLEMS
npm ERR! invalid: @my-ui-fwk/core@1.22.0 D:\my-ui-web\node_modules\@my-ui-fwk\lab\node_modules\@my-ui-fwk\core
my-ui-web@0.1.0 D:\my-ui-web
+-- @my-ui-fwk/core@1.16.0 overridden
+-- @my-ui-fwk/data-grid@1.0.3 overridden
| +-- @my-ui-fwk/core@1.16.0 deduped
| `-- @my-ui-fwk/lab@1.0.0-alpha.4 overridden
|   `-- @my-ui-fwk/core@1.16.0 deduped
`-- @my-ui-fwk/lab@1.0.0-alpha.38 overridden
  `-- @my-ui-fwk/core@1.22.0 invalid: "1.16.0" from node_modules/@my-ui-fwk/lab overridden

What does the error actually mean? And also on the last line, where it says "invalid: "1.16.0" from node_modules/@my-ui-fwk/lab overridden".
I am trying to override @my-ui-fwk/core in my package.json as below. Is there any problem with the above syntax?
  "overrides": {
    "@my-ui-fwk/data-grid": {
      "@my-ui-fwk/core": "$@my-ui-fwk/core"
    },
    "@my-ui-fwk/lab": {
      "@my-ui-fwk/core": "$@my-ui-fwk/core"
    }
  }


Does this answer your question? What does npm ERR! code ELSPROBLEMS mean?

ELSPROBLEMS just means that there is a problem with an invalid package.
npm ERR! invalid: @my-ui-fwk/core@1.22.0 suggests that the version of @my-ui-fwk/core being used (1.22.0) is considered invalid. This might be due to conflicts or inconsistencies in your dependencies
Possible solutions:

Check Dependencies: Verify that the versions specified in your package.json are compatible and consistent.
Remove node_modules and package-lock.json: Sometimes, issues arise due to cached or outdated data. Delete the node_modules folder and the package-lock.json file, then run npm install again.
Update Dependencies: Ensure that you’re using the latest versions of your dependencies. Run npm outdated to check for outdated packages and update them as needed.


thanks...Just one last question....After adding overrides and running "npm i --package-lock-only" command, is there some specific change we can look for in package-lock.json to validate that the "overrides" change has been applied ?

I think there is also an overrides section in the package-lock too. If its there it should be applied.

Oh Wow...That is awesome...And also you do not see any issue with this syntax for overrides...."@my-ui-fwk/core": "$@my-ui-fwk/core"

Actually just realized...I do not see overrides section in package-lock...so might be some other way to validate...But that's fine...I'll have a look
